# grails app acting as own openid provider

Tags: grails, openid, provider, consumer, osqa

I am using Grails 2.1.1 with Spring Security and there is a link from my app to another site on the same server as my grails app, where I am using osqa (http://www.osqa.net). I want, that users can register in my grails app normally with spring security but with these credentials, they shall also be able to login in my osqa app. Thus, I have to use openid, where my grails app is the openId provider and the osqa app is a consumer.

Now, my question is, how I can configure my grails app with spring security as an openid provider. I checked out the spring security openid plugin and doc site, but there, it is just explained how I can configure an openid login via google.